# discord.py client.send_message gets ignored without sending an error

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm trying to make a function for my bot to save quotes. Basically by calling the command quote with a user and then the quote to be saved, example:

> /quote @test I am the best

The program manages to save the quotes no problem, but when it encounters either a client.send_message() or client.say() (I've tried both) it seems to completly ignore them and move on with the rest of the code without raising an error or sending a message. I've tried putting both a send_message a say with only a string each in the beginning of the command, but they still don't send anything (while other commands have no problem at all).

The command:

```
@bot.command()
async def quote(user : discord.Member, *words):#gets the user and then makes a list of all other words

    print(user.id)#a string of numbers
    print(testserver.get_member(user.id) == user)#evaluates to True, this is the reason i use user.id, so that its possible to create a member some other time.

    quoteshelf = shelve.open('quotes')
    quote = ''
    for i in range(len(words)):
        quote = quote + ' ' + words[i]

    bot.say('hi')#tests which have not been working
    bot.send_message(testserver, 'bye')

    if user.id in quoteshelf.keys():#checks if the user already exists in the file
        tempshelf = quoteshelf[user.id]#it isnt possible to append directly into the shelf (or at least it seems so)
        tempshelf.append({quote : getdate()})
        quoteshelf[user.id] = tempshelf

        bot.say('work pls')
        bot.send_message(user.server, 'Added: ' + ' to')
        print(1)
        print(quoteshelf[user.id])

    else:#if it isnt in the file then it will create a new one
        quoteshelf[user.id] = [{quote : getdate()}]
        print(2)
        print(quoteshelf[user.id])
        print(user.server)
        print(user.server == testserver)
        bot.say('ok sure')
        bot.send_message(user.server, 'Created directory for and added ')
        print(2)
    quoteshelf.close()
```

The prints are mostly for debugging (I figured I'd keep them in since they might help understand what this command is doing.

I expect this to save the quote with shelf and then send a short confirmation to the channel but well, the second part I can't seem to make work.

So yeah, I appreciate any pointers in the right direction and just tell me if you need to know anything more. Thanks!

(Edit)
A cleaned up version:

```
@bot.command()
async def quote(user : discord.Member, *words):
    quoteshelf = shelve.open('quotes')
    quote = ''
    for i in range(len(words)):
        quote = quote + ' ' + words[i]

    if user.id in quoteshelf.keys():
        tempshelf = quoteshelf[user.id]
        tempshelf.append({quote : getdate()})
        quoteshelf[user.id] = tempshelf
        bot.say(user.server, 'Added: ' + quote + ' to ' + user.name)

    else:
        quoteshelf[user.id] = [{quote : getdate()}]
        bot.say('Created directory for ' + user.name + ' and added ' + quote)

    quoteshelf.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Boy do i feel stupid atm, I just realised that I've forgotten await before every single one of them. So yeah, if anyone has a similar problem, make sure you didn't forget await...

Comment: Haha, a classic mistake